# How to login into Twitter once and then open twitter links without getting login interrupt?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automation, bots

I am working on a Twitter bot. What twitter bot do is as follows:
First of all, bot will open twitter.com and will login to Twitter.
1- Bot uses an excel file having hundreds of links.(provided to bot)
2- Bot reads the first link and opens it in the tab but the problem is that I am opening the new link with this command: driver.get(link)
It opens a new browser and it needs to login again as previous browser gets closed and new opens every time bot reads a new link from the file. I want to add such a functionality in the code that it login once and then work for all the links and don't ask to login again and again.
This is the code part that I am currently using after just logging in once.

```
with open('link.csv') as csvfile:
csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
for row in csvReader:
    link = row[0]
    comment_no = row[1]
    driver.get(link)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)

    # reply button
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@aria-label='Reply']").click()

    driver.implicitly_wait(2)

    #message box
    message_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//div[@class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr"]')
    message_box.send_keys(answers_list[int(comment_no)])

    tweet_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='toolBar']//div[2]//div[2]//div[1]")
    tweet_button.click()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

If anybody have any solution, Please come forward. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

This is because of selenium uses empty profile. You need to load profile to your selenium.

Thats the example for Chrome:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Path") #Path mean your chrome profile
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

Maybe you need to use "r" before `"user-data-dir=C:\\Path"`